# Как проверить наличие списка в списке

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно проверить наличие списка в списке. Я пробовал

```
if  ["reply_message"] in id:
```

где `id` - это список с большим количеством значений и списков. Не вышло...

Comment: Пробовал, и что?

Comment: Не вышло, что ?  Покажите пример, который вы пробовали.

Comment: у меня такой же питон и вышло

Comment: `if ["reply_message"] in id:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` вернуло эту ошибку

Comment: `{'count': 1, 'items': [{'date': 1588877619, 'from_id': 483988681, 'id': 1616608, 'out': 1, 'peer_id': 2000000125, 'text': '.id', 'conversation_message_id': 6826, 'fwd_messages': [], 'important': False, 'random_id': 45067619, 'attachments': [], 'is_hidden': False, 'reply_message': {'date': 1588877339, 'from_id': 486259400, 'text': 'Текст', 'attachments': [], 'conversation_message_id': 6825, 'peer_id': 2000000125, 'id': 1616603}}]}` в этом списке нужно проверить наличие reply message

Comment: А это не список.

Answer (score 1):

```
for item in id['items']:
    if "reply_message" in item:
        # какой-то код
```

PS: Не используйте id в качестве имени переменной - это зарезервированное слово.

И почитайте хотя бы основы питона. Если вы даже не понимаете отличие списка от словаря и концепцию доступа ко вложенным структурам данных - то вам рано писать реальный код.